# How to Add Default List from Dropdown using Excel VBA then Do something when a Submit button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

How do I put default values on my dropdown?

I tried view code but I'm not sure how to or what codes should I put in there.

I tried

```vb
DropDown7.List = Array("Link 1", "Link 2")
```

in `Sub DropDown7_Change()` of the module.
I used combo box and button and they are on a sheet.

I need to create a dropdown list that when the user clicks on a specific value, it will do something. I have this on my sheet:

[image]

For example, I have "Link 1" and "Link 2" values on the dropdown list and then when I select "Link 1" then "GO TO LINK" button, it will be redirected to the link for Link 1.

Comment: What did you try by your own? What control type are the ones you show us? Are them on a `UserForm` or on a sheet?

Comment: I tried the code "DropDown7.List = Array("Link 1", "Link 2")" and insert in into the Sub DropDown7_Change() of the module. Don't know if I'm doing it right. I used combo box and button and they are on a sheet @FaneDuru.

Comment: So, if I would say that you are talking about a sheet combo `Form` type, should it be a correct statement? If an `ActiveX` the way you tried should work. A `Form` combo box cannot be loaded in that way. You can use an array but iterate it and add its element using addItem.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try it in the next way:

```
Sub fillDropDown()
 Dim cB As DropDown, arr, El
 Set cB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("DropDown7").OLEFormat.Object
 arr = Split("https://google.com,https://example.microsoft.com,a wrong link", ",")
 cB.RemoveAllItems
 For Each El In arr
    cB.AddItem El
 Next
End Sub
```

Copy the above code in a standard module, or in a sheet code module, and run it. If the sheet will be the one keeping the combo, you can use `Me` instead of `ActiveSheet`.

It will load in the combo (dropDown) the array elements.

You can build the array in the next way, too:

```
  arr = Array("https://google.com", "https://example.microsoft.com", "a wrong link")
```

Then, use the next code to access the hyperlink:

```
Sub runHyperlink()
    Dim cB As DropDown, arr, El
    Set cB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("DropDown7").OLEFormat.Object
    If cB.Value <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
         ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=cB.list(cB.Value)
         If Err.Number = -2147221014 Then
            Err.Clear: MsgBox "The used link is not valid..."
         End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        MsgBox "You should select an option in the combo..."
    End If
End Sub
```

You can assign the above code to a `Form`, `shape` button or place it in a `Click` event of an `ActiveX` button. The code or call the sub, simple writing: `runHyperlink` in the event code.

Comment: @Xev Did you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, doesn't it solve your problem? Are there aspects you do not understand and need clarification?